# Problem with using Compose inside a fragment

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

if i try the example often mentioned:

```
class ComposeUIFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            setContent {
                Text(text = "Hello world.")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i get the following errors:

> ```
> @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function
> ```

and

> ```
> Type mismatch.
> Required:
> View?
> Found:
> Unit
> ```

Any idea why?

Comment: your code is correct, make sure the error is from this code, also check if you have `import androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView`